# Mitsubishi Montero limited Have EXCESS FUEL consumption

Tags: fuel-consumption, mitsubishi, montero

My Fairly used Mitsubishi Montero limited 2000 model has excess fuel consumption like 30litrs per 100km
Accompany with very hot interior under the feet even with a c on though vehicle not doing overheating.
Mechanics seems not to know the cause of the excess hotness & excessive fuel even when many news fittings changed including catalyst as suggested to no avail.
Sensors have been removed & tested ok.
Mechanics have confirmed engine running well & in superb form even from the sound of it.
Am contemplating outright sale due to drain on my finance due to this issue.
Please I need technical suggestions & practical help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did they scan the vehicle to see what the long term/short term fuel trims are running at? What diagnostics if any were run? Which engine in your Montero? As for the heat, if the engine is dumping a lot of fuel and is not getting burned *inside* the engine, they will burn *outside* the engine in the catalytic converters. When this happens, the cats heat up tremendously, which could easily explain the heat beneath your feet.